# main packages in go 1.18.1 built-in libraries

Tags: go, version

I am trying to upgrade my project's golang version from `1.15` to `1.18.1`. I changed the version in `go.mod` and executed `go mod tidy` command.

Weird thing, I got following error in my main file which has a `main` function inside itself:

```
'main' collides with name declared in this package
```

It happens for `net/http` and `syscall` libraries:

- net/http

  ```
  Found several packages [http, main] in '/usr/local/go-1.18.1/src/net/http;/usr/local/go-1.18.1/src/net/http'
  ```
- syscall

  ```
  Found several packages [syscall, main] in '/usr/local/go-1.18.1/src/syscall;/usr/local/go-1.18.1/src/syscall'
  ```

As I checked the warning was correct and there were main packages in both libraries.

Should I use an alternative library or should I change the way I import them?

**Edit 1:**

This is an IDE error and I use Goland.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was [reported recently](https://blog.csdn.net/jin1366101575/article/details/123935434) (Apr. 2022) (link in Chinese)

[image: https://img-blog.csdnimg.cn/d93c6e9fb3584a00a52bf1949da1ee02.png?x-oss-process=image/watermark,type_d3F5LXplbmhlaQ,shadow_50,text_Q1NETiBAS2lt6YeRNg==,size_20,color_FFFFFF,t_70,g_se,x_16]

The translation of the relevant comment is:

> The reason for the above error: Your Go language version has been upgraded, and the IDE version is too old to support it.
>
> For example, in my case, Go was upgraded to 1.18, and Goland was not upgraded.

So make sure your IDE (GoLand or VSCode) is fully updated (with, for VSCode, the [latest `gopls`](https://github.com/golang/tools/releases/)).